# jQuery - If div clicked or Esc Key

Tags: jquery

I struggle with something that seems like it should be very easy to solve, but I couldn't yet.

I want  function to be triggered by either a click on one of the two elements or by Escape Key. Just any of them.

To trigger the function by the click on any of the elements is easy.

```
$(".element1, .element2").click(function()  {
    // do stuff
}
```

But how can I make an IF statement, where I ask if either any of the two divs was clicked or the Esc Key is pressed then do ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 handlers

```
//when click on either of these elements myHandler will be called
$(".element1, .element2").click(myHandler);
//on keyup on the document we check whether it is the escape key then call myHandler
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 27) {
        myHandler();
    }
})

function myHandler() {
    //your stuff
    console.log('stuff goes here')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/0wk5tnn8/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fu258ve5/1/)

```
//query and bind elements by ID
$("#element1, #element2").click(tocall);

//hook escape event
**//In fiddle click on result pane to check escape event**
$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
       tocall();
    }
});
//JS handler function
function tocall()  {
    var d = new Date();
    $('#output').html(d.getTime()); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you as well!
Just out of curiosityy, is there no other way to ask "either or any of that triggers happend" within an IF statement like I could in PHP?

Comment: You can send a variable to the "tocall" method above. As this method is being called by respective event handlers they know whether div has been clicked or esc was pressed.